# Test whether each function is continuous at the given point. If the function is not continuous, state the type of discontinuity.

Tags: calculus

Just need a little help with this assignment I'm working on.

Thank you! =)

Just a couple of examples of the questions:

$f(x) = \frac{x+3}{x^2 - 6x + 8 } $ At X = 2

$f(x) = \frac{2x^2 + 7x - 15}{x^2 + 6x + 5} $ At X = -5

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2 - 6x + 8 =(x-2)(x-4)=0$ so
$f(x) = \frac{x+3}{x^2 - 6x + 8 } $ in $\mathbb{R}-\{2,4\}$ is continuous.

$x^2 + 6x + 5=(x+2)(x+3)=0$ so
$f(x) = \frac{2x^2 + 7x - 15}{x^2 + 6x + 5} $ in $\mathbb{R}-\{-3,-5\}$ is continuous.

Comment: welcome dear :)